# Return file and JSON from servlet

Tags: java, servlets

How I can return from Java servlet file stream and some other params (for example JSON) within one response? I believe it achievable, because we return from servlet byte-stream and it can contain file stream and JSON stream. But I think this is very error-prone to try parse such request myself, so I need some library to parse response params.  I don't want to make 2 separate requests..

Answer (score 2):

You could return it all as JSON, encoding the binary stream in base64 and including it in the JSON response. It wouldn't necessarily be efficient but it depends upon the sizes involved.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [`ServletResponse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html) Java doc

- To send binary data in a MIME body response, use the ServletOutputStream returned by getOutputStream().
- To send character data, use the PrintWriter object returned by getWriter().
- To mix binary and text data, for example, to create a multipart response, use a ServletOutputStream and manage the character sections manually.

So you could combine both in output stream and extract when processing the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Multipart. One part for your JSON, one for the other content.

The principle is to build a multi part [MimeMessage](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html) that you return within the synchronous/asynchronous response.